# Google Drive API can't set permissions with reusable upload

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

When I did a basic file upload & set the permission like so, it worked great:

```
$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));

$permissions = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    "role" => "reader",
    "type" => "anyone",
));

$setPermission = $service->permissions->create($file->id, $permissions);
```

But when I upload a large file that's split into chunks & use the resumable uploadType, the permissions aren't set on the file & I don't get any errors:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->title = $fileName;
$file->name = $fileName;

$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
$mimeType = mime_content_type($fullpath);

// Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
$client->setDefer(true);
$request = $service->files->create($file);

// Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $client,
    $request,
    $mimeType,
    null,
    true,
    $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize(filesize($fullpath));

// Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is complete.
$status = false;
$handle = fopen($fullpath, "rb");
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
}

// The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object that has been uploaded.
$result = false;
if($status != false) {
    $result = $status;
    error_log($result->id);
}

fclose($handle);

$permissions = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    "role" => "reader",
    "type" => "anyone"
));

$setPermission = $service->permissions->create($result->id, $permissions);
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same situation with you. In that case, when the file information is retrieved with `$res = $service->files->get($result->id);` after the file was uploaded with the resumable upload, the empty object of `{}` is returned without error. I thought that this is the reason of the issue.

So, I used the following workaround. In this workaround, after the file was uploaded with the resumable upload, I retrieved `$client` again. By this, `$res = $service->files->get($result->id);` worked after the file was uploaded. When this is used for your script, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
fclose($handle);

$permissions = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    "role" => "reader",
    "type" => "anyone"
));

$setPermission = $service->permissions->create($result->id, $permissions);
```

#### To:

```
fclose($handle);

$client = getClient();  // <--- Added
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);  // <--- Added

$permissions = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    "role" => "reader",
    "type" => "anyone"
));

$setPermission = $service->permissions->create($result->id, $permissions);
```

- `getClient()` is for retrieving `$client`. So please modify this part for your actual situation.

#### Note:

- This answer supposes that your `$client` can be created the permissions to the uploaded file. Please be careful this.

Comment: Hmmm, I get undefined function for getClient(), but when I added
`$client = new Google_Client();`
It worked perfectly, so thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

$client->setDefer(true); is causing the issue. That's why it works when you create a new instance of Google client.

Another fix might be to do $client->setDefer(false); after uploading the file.

Comment: What does setDefer do anyway? From looking at the source it looks like its intended for batch operations but was never implemented (the only place it seems to be used is to throw an exception)... And why would you want batch operations in this case anyway?